# Status of mysql and apache services in Xampp using java (running/not running)

Tags: java, mysql, apache, service, xampp

I'm writing a program that uses `mysql` for data fetching and data storage. On its first `jFrame` it creates Database and all necessary table if program is being used for the first time.
 In Later attempts it connect to that Database environment. I want to know how with `java code` can I check if `mysql service` and `apache service` is running or not. If services are not running I have to run those.
I have this piece of code to run services

```
 1. Process process =
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqld.exe");
 2. Process process =
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe");
```

But how can I get their **Status** (running / not running).

Comment: Try to connect to apache and mysql and report if connect failed. I do not suggest to manually start the server processes. This creates a strong dependency between your program and the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code this is not the best way But it is one of the way with which you can do you work.
Check the code below

```
public boolean isServerUp(int port) {
        boolean isUp = false;
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
//            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", port); <- also this
            // Server is up
            isUp = true;
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Server is down
        }
        return isUp;
    }
```

you can also use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`.
And can use this code for checking and running the services

```
boolean isApacheRunning = f.isServerUp(82);
boolean isMySqlRunning = f.isServerUp(3306);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Is tomcat Running = " + isApacheRunning + "\nIs mysql Running = " + isMySqlRunning);
            if (!isMySqlRunning){
                f.RunMySQL();
            }
            if (!isApacheRunning){
                f.RunApache();
            }
```

`f` in the above code is reference of `Functions class` and `RunMySQL();` & `RunApache();` are methods to start services that contain code as in your question.